# Outputting array elements one at a time

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml, element

Currently I am pushing form data (a single text field) to an empty array so that every time I click 'submit' the data is pushed to the end of the array (and thus, the array gets larger)

What I am experiencing:
I would like to output each element in a table, but I would like to do it one element per row, but right now it outputs like this per row

First row: Data entered and submit pressed once -> enteredData

Second row: More data entered and submit pressed -> enteredData
                                                    enteredData1

If I enter another element it does
enteredData
enteredData1
enteredData2
And so forth and so on....

Here's the code block that I have looping:
    userInputName.push(userString);

```
for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < userInputName.length; arrayIndex++) {    
    output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + userInputName[arrayIndex] + "</td></tr>";

}
```

I feel like I'm missing some kind of conditional logic inside the for loop, but at this moment (too little sleep) I can't piece it together rationally :|

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

This is what my full javascript code block looks like--I may reference this to my other thread asking a related question:

```
//Declare global variable
var userInputName       = [];
function displayTableAndTotals() {
// Your code goes in here.
//var totalStrings      = [];
var userString;
var arrayIndex;
var output;
var outputTotal;
var form;

form                = document.getElementById("userFormId");
output              = document.getElementById("userEntriesId");
outputTotal         = document.getElementById("testId");
userString          = form.string.value;

userInputName.push(userString);

for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < userInputName.length; arrayIndex++) {    
    output.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + userInputName[arrayIndex] + "</td></tr>";

}

form.string.select();
return false;   
}
```

Comment: Post some of the code.

Comment: @dfsq, I updated my original post to include the full javascript block

Answer (score 1):

you could just add the pushed element

```
var table = document.querySelector('#myTable');

document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    table.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + userInputName.reverse()[0] + "</td></tr>";
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Good grief, of course I solve my own problem AFTER I spent forever agonizing and then consulting.

Basically I needed to do this:

```
for (arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex < userInputName.length; arrayIndex++) {    
    tableData = "<tr><td>" + userInputName[arrayIndex] + "</td></tr>";
    totalCount = userInputName.length;
}

output.innerHTML += tableData;
outputTotal.innerHTML = "<h4>Total Number of Strings: " + totalCount + "</h4>";

form.string.select();
return false;
```

So that the tableData variable would contain a new iteration without constantly resubmitting the entire thing every time.  That way I could output tableData outside the loop properly.

I appreciate the feedback I have received.

Thank you!